# How can i use Github Token in Netbeans 12.0?

Tags: authentication, github, netbeans, token

I am using Netbeans 12. I was using gihub with password, but now github ask me token. How can i set the token in existing project on Apache Netbeans 12.0.

Answer (score 5):

Open your Netbeans project.

Open an internet browser, log in to your GitHub account and create a "Personal access token" (see GitHub doc, super easy), copy it.

Then in Netbeans select your project and use the Git menu to push or pull from the GitHub repo: Netbeans will prompt you for a user and a password. **Use your GitHub login name and the Personal access token as the password**.

Netbeans will save it on your computer, it won't ask it anymore, unless access rights of your GitHub account change.

Comment: Is it still valid?
Did tried but keeps prompting me with the form to enter username and password again and again.

Comment: I changed my computer 1 month ago and had to do it again, it was still valid at that time.

Comment: I could not make it work with the Personal access token.
I had to switch to openssh key.